# How to declare array and add items on same line?

Tags: swift

I'd like to declare a custom typed array and add several items.

```
class ClassA:NSObject {
  var property1: String?
  var property2: String?
}

var myarray = [ClassA]()
```

How do I add new instances of ClassA to the array on the same line as the above declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a custom initializer and use type inference on the array like so:

```
class ClassA: NSObject {
    var property1: String?
    var property2: String?

    init(property1: String, property2: String) {
        super.init()
        self.property1 = property1
        self.property2 = property2
    }
}

// ...

var myarray = [
    ClassA(property1: "A1", property2: "B1"),
    ClassA(property1: "A2", property2: "B2"),
    ClassA(property1: "A3", property2: "B3"),
    ClassA(property1: "A4", property2: "B4"),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
 var myarray = [ClassA()]
```

or

```
var myarray = [ClassA](count: 10, repeatedValue: ClassA())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way :

```
var classAarray: [ClassA] = []
var newClassA = ClassA()
classAarray.append(newClassA)
```

Or this way :

```
var classAarray: [ClassA] = [ClassA(), ClassA(), ClassA()]
```

Have look at [Apple Documentation reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) to do more actions on Array